# Getting No API request if hitting the API in one hour interval

Tags: python, aws-lambda, boto3, aws-event-bridge

Getting "No API request" message when I hit the API in one hour of interval.

Actually I need a code where if any 4xx, 5xx and request not made in hour scenario will be there for the other api then my this code should send me an alert mail.

I tried this code from chatgpt but after hitting the other api within the 1 hour of interval this code throw me a message of No API request.
For Error the code is working fine but want solution for above problem of 1 hour

CODE:

```
############## NEW CODE IF API REQUEST IS NOT MADE IN AN HOUR 
import boto3
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError


def send_email(subject, body, sender, recipient):
    client = boto3.client('ses')

    try:
        response = client.send_email(
            Destination={
                'ToAddresses': [recipient]
            },
            Message={
                'Body': {
                    'Html': {
                        'Charset': 'UTF-8',
                        'Data': body
                    },
                },
                'Subject': {
                    'Charset': 'UTF-8',
                    'Data': subject
                },
            },
            Source=sender
        )
    except ClientError as e:
        print('Error sending email:', e.response['Error']['Message'])
    else:
        print('Email sent! Message ID:', response['MessageId'])

def check_logs_for_errors(log_group_name):
    client = boto3.client('logs')

    response = client.describe_log_streams(
        logGroupName=log_group_name,
        orderBy='LastEventTime',
        descending=True,
        limit=10
    )

    if 'logStreams' in response:
        log_stream_name = response['logStreams'][0]['logStreamName']
        print('Checking logs in stream:', log_stream_name)

        response = client.get_log_events(
            logGroupName=log_group_name,
            logStreamName=log_stream_name,
            limit=10,
            startFromHead=True
        )

        
        for event in response['events']:
                if 'ERROR' in event['message']:
                return True
        

    return False


def check_recent_api_requests(log_group_name):
    client = boto3.client('logs')
    
        
    utc_now = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
    one_hour_from_now = utc_now - timedelta(hours=1)
    print('one_hour_from_now',one_hour_from_now)
    timestamp = int(one_hour_from_now.timestamp() * 1000)
    
    
    
    
    response = client.filter_log_events(
        logGroupName=log_group_name,
        startTime=timestamp,
        filterPattern='api_request',
        limit=10
    )
    
    
    
    
    # print("response", response)
    if 'events' not in response or len(response['events']) == 0:
        return True

    return False


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    log_group_name = '/aws/lambda/RC_Book_OCR'
    sender = 'example@gmail.com'
    recipient = 'example@gmail.com'
    
    #     ######## TO RETRIVE THE LAMBDA FUNCTION NAME
    api_name= log_group_name.split("/")[-1]
    
    body_html= f'<html><body><h3><b>***** Please do not reply to this autogenerated email *****</h3></b><br>{api_name}: Errors were detected in the logs.</body></html>'
    body_html1= f'<html><body><h3><b>***** Please do not reply to this autogenerated email *****</h3></b><br>{api_name}: No API requests in the last hour.</body></html>'
    

    error_found = check_logs_for_errors(log_group_name)
    no_api_requests = check_recent_api_requests(log_group_name)

    if error_found:
        # send_email('Error Alert!', body_html, sender, recipient)
        print("YES ERROR")
    elif no_api_requests:
        # send_email('No API Request Alert!', body_html1, sender, recipient)
        print("NO API REQUEST")
        
    else:
        print("No Errors Found in API")

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': 'Alert emails sent successfully.'
    }
```